# php : weird socket_set_nonblock() and socket_connect()

Tags: php

I think there might be some problem with my using socket_set_nonblock(). Without socket_set_nonblock(), socket_select() works, but with socket_set_nonblock(), socket_select() fails. I wrote codes as below.

case 1. fail

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'success' */

socket_set_nonblock($sock);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'success' */

socket_connect($sock, ADDRESS, PORT);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'unable to connect [115]: Operation now in progress' */

$read = array($sock); $write = array($sock);    
socket_select($read, $write, $e=NULL, TIMEOUT);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'unable to connect [115]: Operation now in progress' */
```

case 2. succeed

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'success' */

socket_connect($sock, ADDRESS, PORT);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'success' */

$read = array($sock); $write = array($sock);    
socket_select($read, $write, $e=NULL, TIMEOUT);
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()); /* 'success' */
```

The comments after 'echo's are output of the 'echo's. I can't guess what the problem is. Furthermore, it happens to the only one server I am running. The others are working fine. The environments of the servers are exactly the same. (same os / apache / php version and modules).